# Scala: Expand List of Tuples into variable-length argument list of Tuples

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm puzzled on how to expand List/Seq/Array into variable-length argument list.

Given that I have test_func function accepting tuples:

```
scala> def test_func(t:Tuple2[String,String]*) = println("works!")
test_func: (t: (String, String)*)Unit
```

Which works when I pass tuples:

```
scala> test_func(("1","2"),("3","4"))
works!
```

From reading the Scala reference I've got strong impression that the following whould work as well:

```
scala> test_func(List(("1","2"),("3","4")))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)]
 required: (String, String)
              test_func(List(("1","2"),("3","4")))
                        ^
```

And one more desperate attempt:

```
scala> test_func(List(("1","2"),("3","4")).toSeq)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Seq[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)]
 required: (String, String)
              test_func(List(("1","2"),("3","4")).toSeq)
```

How to expand List/Seq/Array into argument list?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to add `:_*`.

```
scala> test_func(List(("1","2"),("3","4")):_*)
works!
scala> test_func(Seq(("1","2"),("3","4")):_*)
works!
scala> test_func(Array(("1","2"),("3","4")):_*)
works!
```

Comment: Thank you Prince! That worked :) One short q:  `_` here is referencing List element type, i.e. Tuple?

Comment: I wouldn't say `_` is referencing anything. Rather, `_*` is a type annotation that marks `t` as a sequence argument.

Comment: @elbowich:+1. yes. i've wrongly interpreted OP's quiz? removed my comment.